# Cordova-Tizen studio project build error

Tags: cordova, eclipse-cdt, tizen-studio

During project build in tizen studio i got error like

> "Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'CDT
>   Builder'  on project 'cordova-tizen-basic'.
>           Please select a rootstrap again
>           Please select a rootstrap again" [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QG6U.png)

Comment: Try with re-installing Tizen Studio.

Comment: I have already install more than 4 times...But its not worked.

Comment: I have found this link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/getting-started/tizen/ Check this tutorial site.This site https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/ does not include Tizen within Develop for platforms section.